# Howto reduce partial-flushes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a quite simple java application using Hibernate as ORM framework.

That application does fetch (in a single transaction) a few thousand objects from the db and returns them. There are no updates on these entities.

The hibernate stats shows me the following:

```
Session Metrics {
 25042 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
 0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
 1319016 nanoseconds spent preparing 11 JDBC statements;
 83631650 nanoseconds spent executing 11 JDBC statements;
 0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
 83723194 nanoseconds spent performing 1766 L2C hits;
 13593721 nanoseconds spent performing 1764 L2C misses;
 12664271 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 5928 entities and 7755 collections);
16903049699 nanoseconds spent executing 1767 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 10457112 entities and 10457112 collections)
}
```

As you can see I loose a big amount of time when Hibernate is doing the "partial-flushes" stuff.

Can someone please help me to understand what Hibernate exactly does when doing "partial-flushes", and howto reduce these flushes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate executes partial flushes as the transaction list increases, and specifically when the order of the session calls fulfills the template you can find here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing

A way to avoid the partial-flushing is to set the `FlushMode` to `COMMIT` or specifically something like:

```
sess = sf.openSession();
Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
sess.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
```

This will have the effect of holding all of the flushes until the tx.commit() occurs.

I have personally had an issue before, where records would be partially-flushed and db inserts would occur. As these partial flushes updated the database with insert records, when rolling back on failure they weren't being deleted. I had to change the FlushMode to ensure partial flushing was not occurring.

As for the timing, reducing the partial flushes will increase the total time it takes to flush, so you will need to see if the trade-off is worth it.